# How to connect to AWS MSK using SASL

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafkajs

I have created an MSK Cluster in AWS and trying to connect to it from my local node app. I am using kafkajs for making kafka client but not able to connect to cluster.

I have been trying to establish connection like this as described in kafkajs documentation.

```
this.kafka = new Kafka({
          clientId: 'user_service', // Replace with your desired client ID
          brokers: ['b-1-public.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.c3.kafka.xxxxxxx1.amazonaws.com:9196'],
          sasl: {
            mechanism: 'plain',
            username: 'bloom-msk',
            password: "bloom-msk-dev-secret"
          },
        });
```

While running this I am getting following error:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-11-23T11:43:55.513Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Closed connection","retryCount":5,"retryTime":6586}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionClosedError: Closed connection
```

For IAM I followed the following steps, and not able to connect. Error is still saying "Closed Connection"

- Made the IAM user named kafka-user
- Created role with MSKFullAccess policy and gave that role to user
- for that user created access keys
- made an inbound rule in the security group for allowing All traffic

Using following code:

```
this.kafka = new Kafka({
      clientId: 'user_service', // Replace with your desired client ID
      brokers: ['KAFKA_BROKER_ADDRESS'],
      sasl: {
        mechanism: 'aws',
        authorizationIdentity: 'kafka-user', // UserId or RoleId
        accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
        secretAccessKey: 'ACCESS_SECRET',
        // sessionToken: '' // Optional
      },
    });
```

I commented the sessionToken as it is optional and I do not know how to get it.

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Why not use IAM access? Your username and password should never be in plaintext

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I have tried that too but it was not working. Then I moved to SASL username/password thing. If you have done it can you suggest some blog or tell me the exact steps to set it up? It would be of great help.

Comment: @Quassnoi, When I run this code I get the following error 
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-11-23T11:43:55.513Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[BrokerPool] Closed connection","retryCount":5,"retryTime":6586}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

KafkaJSNonRetriableError
  Caused by: KafkaJSConnectionClosedError: Closed connection

Comment: @V0idHat: please add it to your question

Comment: I've been able to use IAM exactly following the kafkajs documentation

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have described what I have done for IAM method. Can you share exact steps of how to setup cluster with IAM, What policies to make and how to make user to access it, what credentials to use and what rules to be defined in security groups?

Comment: There's example code in the MSK docs to help with this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html#how-to-use-iam-access-control Again, your secret keys shouldn't be plaintext in your code

Comment: Already tried it, @OneCricketeer. Actually now i am able to run commands in cluster through kafka cli but not able to run from my application. Its showing same error.

Comment: Refer to the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77543123/kafka-msk-connection-error-when-using-kafkajs/77575907#77575907